# How many of the August protesters were actually from the Romanian diaspora?

Tags: protests, romania

It's been widely reported in the Western news that e.g. ["Romanian diaspora’s anti-government protest turns violent"](https://www.politico.eu/article/romanian-diaspora-anti-government-protest-turns-violent-psd-klaus-iohannis-viorica-dancila/):

> A major anti-government protest held in Bucharest by Romanians living abroad turned violent Friday, with at least 250 people requiring medical care, local media reported.
>
> Romanians drove for days from countries including England, Italy and Switzerland to protest against the policies of the ruling Social Democratic Party (PSD) [...]
>
> Between 80,000 and 100,000 people gathered in front of the government building in Victoria Square, according to Romanian media.

That doesn't quite say how many of these protesters were actually from the diaspora. Is it really the case that a substantial enough number (e.g. a majority of these ~100k) were actually from the diaspora to make the headlines talking of the "diaspora’s protest" justified?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to find an estimate of the number of persons coming from aboard (Romanian diaspora), both in local press and international and I could not find any. However, I am able to partially provide an answer.

Ref to "diaspora’s protest" the name was given because diaspora acted as an initiator ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2017%E2%80%932019_Romanian_protests)):

> Fresh anti-government protests took place on August 10th 2018. The
>   event, entitled "Diaspora at Home" **was organized and
>   promoted by Romanians living abroad**

I remember that a diaspora organization asked for approval more than one month before the actual protest and got rejected.

Since I was there and walked around, I would say that there was a significant number of diaspora persons (based on the way they talked), but clearly not the majority. There were many from Bucharest (it is easy to get to Victory Square from virtually everywhere by subway), but also from other Romanian cities.

I would guesstimate somewhere between 1/5 and 1/3 of people from Romanian diaspora.